# std::ofstream not creating file when called from constructor from global object

Tags: c++

To begin - the code as written works in Linux, but when building and running on Windows the log file is not created.

I've created a simple Logging library and that should create a file local to the executable.

Logger.h

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

namespace Logger
{
    enum class Level
    {
        DEBUG,
        INFO,
        WARNING,
        ERROR
    };

    std::string GetTime();

    class Log
    {
    private:
        std::string filename;
        std::stringstream inStr;
        std::ofstream logFile;
        std::recursive_mutex inStrMutex;
        std::mutex fileMutex;

        void ClearStrStream();
        std::string LevelToString(Level lvl);

    public:
        Log(std::string file);
        ~Log();

        template<typename T>
        void Write(Level lvl, const T& arg)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> inStrLock(inStrMutex);
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> fileLock(fileMutex);

            inStr << std::noskipws << arg << '\n';
            logFile << std::noskipws << "[" << GetTime() << "]"
                    << "[" << LevelToString(lvl) << "] "
                    << inStr.str();

            ClearStrStream();

            return;
        }

        template<typename T, typename... Args>
        void Write(Level lvl, const T& firstArg, Args... args)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(inStrMutex);
            inStr << std::noskipws << firstArg;
            Write(lvl, args...);
            return;
        }

    };
}

#endif
```

The constructor defined in Logger.cpp

```
Logger::Log::Log(std::string file) : filename{ file }
{
    std::cout << "Ctor called\n";
    auto now = Logger::GetTime();
    auto fullName =  now + "_" + filename;
    logFile = std::ofstream(fullName);

    inStr = std::stringstream("", std::ios_base::ate | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::in);
}
```

This gets built into a static library and then linked in LoggerUnitTest.cpp

```
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

#include "Logger.h"
#include "LoggerConfig.h"
#include "date.h"

Logger::Log GLogObject("LoggerTest.log");

void WriteToLogger()
{
    GLogObject.Write(Logger::Level::WARNING,
                     "The quick brown ",
                     "fox jumps ",
                     "over the ",
                     "lazy ",
                     "dog.");

    GLogObject.Write(Logger::Level::ERROR,
                     "Because nighttime ",
                     "is the best time ",
                     "to fight crime.");

    return;
}

void TestMultipleTypes()
{
    GLogObject.Write(Logger::Level::DEBUG,
                     "String ",
                     123,
                     " and integer.");

    return;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Testing Logger Version: " << LOGGER_VERSION_MAJOR << "."
              << LOGGER_VERSION_MINOR << std::endl;

    std::thread t1(TestMultipleTypes);
    std::thread t2(WriteToLogger);
    WriteToLogger();
    std::thread t3(WriteToLogger);
    WriteToLogger();
    std::thread t4(WriteToLogger);
    std::thread t5(WriteToLogger);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    t5.join();

    return 0;
}
```

When LoggerUnitTest is built and run in Linux, things work as expected.  A log file is created and everything is written into the log file as expected.

When LoggerUnitTest is build and run in Windows, LoggerUnitTest.exe runs, but no log file is created.  What's different about Windows that results in no file being written?

I've also attempted to explicitly add `std::flush` in Logger's Write function which doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Which path did you check and found log file isn't existed?

Comment: First checked same directory as executable, then searched entire project directory structure and was unable to find the .log file.

Comment: I tested [this](https://godbolt.org/z/1Mfzon) on windows and it creates the file in the directory same as executable. So the issue might not be `ofstream`. You need a [mre].

Comment: You are missing `~Log()`, `GetTime()`, `ClearStrStream`, `LevelToString`,  etc.

Comment: *When LoggerUnitTest is build and run in Windows* -- Which compiler?  Which compiler settings?  Stubbing out the missing functions you have, the program creates a log file successfully using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @LouisGo - creating the ofstream object like you did works for me as well.  When the ofstream object is initialized from the Logger constructor, the log files is not written.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - that's interesting, I''ll try building and running from VisualStudio.  I've been using CMake and MSBuild.  Here are the relevant version numbers:-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19041.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29110.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29110.0

Comment: Just like Paul said, you didn't not provide enough details of `Logger::Log`.

Comment: [See the code here](https://godbolt.org/z/bh1fPT)

Comment: Hmm, thanks for double checking, there must be something unique to my environment.  I'll keep debugging and keep this thread updated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the way GetTime() returned a date/time formatted string.  The formate was YYYY/mm/DD_HH:MM:SS.  According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file), colons `:` and forward slashes `/` are prohibited characters in file names.  After adjusting the format of the date/time, everything works as expected!